# How to change the font in recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of Button type `TextView`s like  set in a horizontal `RecyclerView` and I'm trying to change the font of the text of these buttons and it's not working.
I've changed the font in the `XML` file of my item to exo, and tried to use many tips of view instead of the `TextView` but i can't change the font anyway.
is there any limitation about customization of the view when using `RecyclerView` or I'm doing it wrong?

p.s. I can't change the padding of the `TextView` either.

My `RecyclerView` item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rpgListBtn"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_rpg_list"
        android:fontFamily="@font/exo_teste"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="D&amp;D"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

My `RecyclerView`:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rpgListView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingLeft="22dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/escolha_um_" />
```

my adapter:

```
package com.example.rpglink.Adapters;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.rpglink.R;
import java.util.List;

public class RpgListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RpgListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<String> titulos;

    public RpgListAdapter(List<String> titulos) {
        this.titulos = titulos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rps_list_view_holder,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String titulo = titulos.get(position);
        holder.titulo.setText(titulo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titulos.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView titulo;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rpgListBtn);
        }
    }
}
```

the implementation of recycler view in the activity:

```
package com.example.rpglink.Activitys;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.rpglink.Adapters.RpgListAdapter;
import com.example.rpglink.Helpers.HorizontalSpaceItemDecoration;
import com.example.rpglink.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeC extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RpgListAdapter adapter;
    private List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    public HomeC() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_c);

    criarTitulos();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rpgListView);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new RpgListAdapter(lista);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalSpaceItemDecoration(32));


    }
    public void criarTitulos(){
    this.lista.add("D&D");
    this.lista.add("CyberPunk");
    this.lista.add("Call of Cthulhu");
    this.lista.add("Tormenta");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in the ViewHolder constructor using [`Typeface.createFromAsset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface#createFromAsset(android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String))

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView titulo;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rpgListBtn);
        titulo.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), 
                                                   "font/exo_teste"));
    }
}
```

Comment: my app crashes and my log cat says:
2020-12-22 17:44:58.574 9521-9521/com.example.rpglink E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rpglink, PID: 9521
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found font/exo.ttf

Comment: the path seens to be right, idk why it doesn't work

Comment: now it works, turned out i had to write the path without the "font/" part, just "exo.ttf"